# Why is lowlatency kernel not being updated in parallel with the generic kernel?

Tags: 12.04, kernel, updates

All,

Any idea when we'll see updates to the lowlatency version of the Ubuntu 12.04 kernel? It is still stuck at 3.2.0.23 whereas the generic kernel is already several updates ahead of it at a version 3.2.0.25?

NB: I am using a 64-bit version but I don't think this is limited to the 64-bit kernels alone but rather affects both 32-bit and 64-bit builds. Please do correct me if I am wrong about this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the lowlatency kernel is not officially supported, but is maintained by the community, who are not as diligent about security fixes as the security team.