# Why is the lowlatency kernel not being updated in parallel with the generic kernel?

Tags: 12.04, kernel, updates

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why is lowlatency kernel not being updated in parallel with the generic kernel?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/153841/why-is-lowlatency-kernel-not-being-updated-in-parallel-with-the-generic-kernel)

I did:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-lowlatency linux-headers-lowlatency
```

I'm trying to get better perfomance for some Audio apps.

It is still stuck at 3.2.0.23 whereas the generic kernel is already several updates ahead of it at a version 3.2.0.26.

What is the update policy on this lowlatency kernel?

Comment: You should file a bug: `ubuntu-bug linux-lowlatency` -- Does 3.2.0.26 have any important changes concerning latency? That's what you should check, not the number of the release.

Comment: Well exactly what kind of better performance is the low-latency kernel  giving you? Or are you simply trying it because it *might*? In other words, what is the problem?